# Bullet doesn't initiate at all when player gets into range

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The problem is that bullet doesn't initiate at all when player gets into range. Here is my code for attack

```
public void Attack(bool attackingRight)
{
    bulletTimer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (bulletTimer >= shootInterval)
    {
        Vector2 direction = target.transform.position - transform.position;
        direction.Normalize();


        if (!attackingRight)
        {

            GameObject bulletClone;


            bulletClone = Instantiate(bullet, shootPointLeft.transform.position, shootPointLeft.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            bulletClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * bulletsSpeed;

            bulletTimer = 0;

        }
        if(attackingRight)
        {
            GameObject bulletClone;  
            bulletClone = Instantiate(bullet, shootPointRight.transform.position, shootPointRight.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            bulletClone.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().velocity = direction * bulletsSpeed;

            bulletTimer = 0;
        }
    }
```

**And this is the other part**

```
public class Attack_Cone : MonoBehaviour {

public TurretAI turretAI;

public bool isLeft = false;



void Awake()
{
    turretAI = gameObject.GetComponentInParent<TurretAI>();

}

void onTriggerStay2D(Collider2D col)
{
    if (col.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        if (isLeft)
        {
            turretAI.Attack(false);
        }
        else
        {
            turretAI.Attack(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Can't figure it out why. Visual Studio doesn't report an error, so doesn't the Unity.

Comment: You could try putting `Debug.Log(col.tag)` before `if (col.CompareTag("Player"))` to make sure your tag is correct. I suspect it weren't :)

Comment: Yeah, debug the hell out of it - debug.log everything and see where it's going wrong. Also, if your bullet has an OnCollision then check it's not colliding with the thing that spawned it, if so change its layer.